# Web Push notification Payload data is getting null

Tags: python, push-notification, service-worker, payload, web-push

Hi I'm trying to implement web push notification for web i followed the following [example](https://serviceworke.rs/push-payload_index_doc.html),except the server part for which i'm using python script to connect to gcm/fcm and generating payload .i'm getting the push event but the event.data coming null .

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyfcm import FCMNotification
pushService = FCMNotification(api_key ='xxx'}
registrationId=""
messageTitle = "New update available"
messageBody ="some message"
dryRun = False
extraData = {}
extraData['title'] = "nknkn"
```

sw.js

```
self.addEventListener('push',function(e){

console.log('Push Message Recevied',e.data);
var title = 'Push message';
e.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {
        body: 'The Message form data',
        icon: 'icon.jpg',
        tag: 'my-tag'
    }));
});
```

Comment: which chrome version you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Both, Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox currently support payload for push messages, see [PushMessageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/PushMessageData#Browser_compatibility) on MDN. But according to the Push API specification, any payload MUST be encrypted, otherwise a browser will discard it and return *null* (see [11.1.6](https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/#the-push-event)):

> If the push message could not be decrypted for any reason, or if it is not encrypted and contains any payload, discard the message and terminate this process. A push message may be empty if it contains no content, but otherwise push event must not be fired for a push message that was not successfully decrypted using the key pair associated with the push subscription.

Here is a good article from Google Developers, which explains it with more details: [Web Push Payload Encryption](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/web-push-encryption). And original draft of the [Message Encryption for Web Push](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-thomson-webpush-encryption).

I also can suggest you to look at the set of already implemented libraries for WebPush on different languages: [web-push-libs](https://github.com/web-push-libs). You can find there a lib written on Python too. And another lib on Java, which can send push messages with a payload to Chrome and Firefox: https://github.com/MartijnDwars/web-push.

Comment: This also must mean that sending bulk notifications is not possible.... or at least very inpractical..  having to send X http requests to X clients, instead of sending to 1000 at a time....