# How to encrypt payload in Java Admin SDK

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I used to use GCM, now I 've passed to FCM.For this reason, right now,  I am sending WebPush Message with Firebase Admin SDK. When I sent  webpush, clients get notification without data. According to texts which I read, I have to encyrpt payload with JWT. However I could not find a way to encyrpt.

I've clientAuthSecret, clientPublicKey and endpoint. I need your leadership.

```
@Override
public WebPushResponse sendMessageToMultipleUsers(List<String> registrationTokens) throws IOException {

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new ClassPathResource(firebaseConfigPath).getInputStream())).build();
    if (FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        logger.info("Firebase application has been initialized");
    }

    MulticastMessage message = MulticastMessage.builder()
            .setWebpushConfig(WebpushConfig.builder()
                    .setNotification(new WebpushNotification("$GOOG up 1.43% on the day",
                            "$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.", "https://my-server/icon.png"))
                    .build())
            .addAllTokens(registrationTokens).build();
    BatchResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendMulticastAsync(message).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (response != null && response.getFailureCount() > 0) {
        List<SendResponse> responses = response.getResponses();
        List<String> failedTokens = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < responses.size(); i++) {
            if (!responses.get(i).isSuccessful()) {
                // The order of responses corresponds to the order of the registration tokens.
                failedTokens.add(registrationTokens.get(i));
            }
        }

        System.out.println("List of tokens that caused failures: " + failedTokens);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you point to the documentation that mentions this encryption requirement?

Comment: Hello @HiranyaJayathilaka,  I read documentaion in the answer of question :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992034/web-push-notification-payload-data-is-getting-null

Comment: None of that applies when sending messages via FCM. Your code snippet sends a notification with no data (only title and body). Therefore I'd expect your browser to display the notification on screen (I've used this feature in a number of my own example apps). Make sure you correctly followed the instructions at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client

Comment: As I understood, I don't use firebase client, that's why the problem occures . I have collected lots of user notification acceptance. || I want to still send push notifications to them. I'm trying to pass GCM to FCM and use VAPID method. Then, I should my implementation instead of Firebase Admin SDK.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka, If you lead me where I should use   "p256dh" and "auth", i can solve this problem.  {"endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/$token","expirationTime":null,"keys":{"p256dh":"ABC","auth":"DEF"}}"